# Frozen Python File Can't access "Save_File"

Tags: python

After packing my program I decided to test it out to make sure it worked, a few things happened, but the main issue is with the Save_File.

I use a Save_File.py for data, static save data. However, the frozen python file can't do anything with this file. It can't write to it, or read from it. Writing says saved successful but on load it resets all values to zero again.

Is it normal for any .py file to do this?

Is it an issue in pyinstaller?

Bad freeze process?

Or is there some other reason that the frozen file can't write, read, or interact with files not already inside it? (Save_File was frozen inside and doesn't work, but removing it causes errors, similar to if it never existed).

So the exe can't see outside of itself or change within itself...

Edit: Added the most basic version of the save file, but basically, it gets deleted and rewritten a lot.

```
def save():
with open("Save_file.py", "a") as file:
    file.write("healthy = " + str(healthy) + "\n")
    file.write("infected = " + str(infected) + "\n")
    file.write("zombies = " + str(zombies) + "\n")
    file.write("dead = " + str(dead) + "\n")
    file.write("cure = " + str(cure) + "\n")
    file.write("week = " + str(week) + "\n")
    file.write("infectivity = " + str(infectivity) + "\n")
    file.write("infectivity_limit = " + str(infectivity_limit) + "\n")
    file.write("severity = " + str(severity) + "\n")
    file.write("severity_limit = " + str(severity_limit) + "\n")
    file.write("lethality = " + str(lethality) + "\n")
    file.write("lethality_limit = " + str(lethality_limit) + "\n")
    file.write("weekly_infections = " + str(weekly_infections) + "\n")
    file.write("dna_points = " + str(dna_points) + "\n")
    file.write("burst = " + str(burst) + "\n")
    file.write("burst_price = " + str(burst_price) + "\n")
    file.write("necrosis = " + str(necrosis) + "\n")
    file.write("necrosis_price = " + str(necrosis_price) + "\n")
    file.write("water = " + str(water) + "\n")
    file.write("water_price = " + str(water_price) + "\n")
    file.write("air = " + str(air) + "\n")
    file.write("blood = " + str(blood) + "\n")
    file.write("saliva = " + str(saliva) + "\n")
    file.write("zombify = " + str(zombify) + "\n")
    file.write("rise = " + str(rise) + "\n")
    file.write("limit = int(" + str(healthy) + " + " + str(infected) + " + " + str(dead) + " + " + str(zombies) + ")\n")
    file.write("old = int(1)\n")
Clear.clear()
WordCore.word_corex("SAVING |", "Save completed successfully")
time.sleep(2)
Clear.clear()
player_menu()
```

Comment: can you show us the code where you're saving the data?

Comment: don't use a python file to save code into it. Rather use a dictionary and use `json.dump` to a text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's probably because the frozen version of the file (somewhere in a .zip file) is loaded and *never* the one you're writing (works when the files aren't frozen)

That's bad practice to:

```
- have a zillion global variables to hold your persistent data
- generate code in a python file just to evaluate it back again (it's _self-modifying code_).
```

If you used C or C++ language, would you generate some code to store your data then compile it in your new executable ? would you declare 300 globals? I don't think so.

You'd be better off with `json` data format and a dictionary for your variables, that would work for frozen or not frozen:

your dictionary would be like:

```
variables = {"healthy" : True, "zombies" : 345}  # and so on
```

Access your variables:

```
if variables["healthy"]:  # do something
```

then save function:

```
import json
def save():
    with open("data.txt", "w") as file:
        json.dump(variables,file,indent=3)
```

creates a text file with data like this:

```
{
   "healthy": true,
   "zombies": 345
}
```

and load function (declaring `variables` as global to avoid creating the same variable, but local only)

```
def load():
   global variables
   with open("data.txt", "r") as file:
       variables = json.load(file)
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me that module, I had no idea it existed. Have barely a year of experience (high school), this made everything that relied on external data to run and be fixed far more easily.